# coverting timestamp to epoch seconds and vice versa in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud

I can run below queries to get the epoch seconds from date and can covert back them to given date in `Google bigquery`.

**For example:**

```
select unix_seconds(timestamp('2020-12-04 00:00:00')), unix_seconds(timestamp('2020-12-04 01:00:00'));

1607040000
1607043600
```

and can covert back them to timestamp.

```
select timestamp_seconds(1607043600);

2020-12-04 01:00:00 UTC
```

I am looking for similar queries in `PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Epoch seconds to UTC timestamp

```sql
SELECT To_Timestamp(1607043600) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ;
```

```
------------------------
 2020-12-04 01:00:00
```

---

#### UTC timestamp to Epoch seconds

```sql
SELECT Extract(epoch From '2020-12-04 01:00:00'::TIMESTAMP) ;
```

```
------------
 1607043600
```